# Setup ElasticSearch Cluster - 8.8 million

Tags: elasticsearch

Need to setup ElasticSearch Cluster in AWS for below requirement and this will be managed by us (we are not preferring ES service provided by AWS).

```
Total documents - 8.8 million 
Total documents size - 500 GBs
Number of Index - 1
```

What would be the best optimal ElasticSearch cluster sizing (AWS EC2 instance type, storage) and number of nodes, shards & replicas.

We could not able to find any reference documents to answering these questions.